# How to use library from NPM workspaces in projects outside the workspace

Tags: reactjs, npm, monorepo, npm-workspaces

I'm looking for direction on how to use the library built using NPM workspaces on the project outside the workspace. I have an app called Green which is a monorepo, the library 'calculator' inside that needs to be used in the Yellow project, the yellow project is on a separate repository outside the monorepo, so how can I use the calculator app inside Yellow project? do I have to publish the library to some registry and use it in Yellow project as an npm library?

Project 1 - Monorepo

```
+-- Green
+-- package.json
`-- app
   +-- HelloWorld
   |   `-- package.json
`-- library
   `-- calculator
   |   `-- package.json
```

Project 2 - Separate repo

```
.
+-- Yellow
+-- package.json
`-- app
```

References I used: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/workspaces?v=true